# Как отправить данные обратно клиенту по UDP?

Tags: linux, c, сервер, сокет, udp

В Википедии нашел код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for close() for socket */ 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_in sa; 
  char buffer[1024];
  ssize_t recsize;
  socklen_t fromlen;

  memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);
  sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  sa.sin_port = htons(7654);
  fromlen = sizeof sa;

  sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa) == -1) {
    perror("error bind failed");
    close(sock);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (;;) {
    recsize = recvfrom(sock, (void*)buffer, sizeof buffer, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, &fromlen);
    if (recsize < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("recsize: %d\n ", (int)recsize);
    sleep(1);
    printf("datagram: %.*s\n", (int)recsize, buffer);
  }
}
```

В нём сокет слушает порт 7654 и выводит данные о принятой от клиента датаграммы на консоль. 
Как передать датаграмму обратно клиенту?

Comment: Вам нужно знать адрес и порт на котором слушает клиент

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [`sendto`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto):

```
sendto(sock, buffer, recsize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, addrlen);
```

Answer (score 2):

Тоже озадачился вопросом. Вот например принял UDP сервер сообщение от клиента, теоретически подставить серверный слушающий сокет в sendto и отправить на IP и порт клиента который определился при приёме собщения сервером. Но на Delphi 6 у меня возникла проблема вопрос задал на Тостере тут https://qna.habr.com/q/787303
Меня вообще интересовала а верная ли логика и можно ли вообще для отправки использовать сокет привязанный как слушающй?

Можно конечно для отправке на сервере отдельный сокет создать и отправить всё на тот же IP и порт клиента которые определились при приёме сообщения сервером. Вот только в этом случаи порт же будет не изначально заданный серверу, а зачит в теле датаграммы потребуется как то пояснить что это именно эта программа отвечает на только что полученное сообщение, но зачем, не ужели это обязательно? Думаю что всё-таки непосредственно серверный слещающий UDP сокет необходимо указывать в sendto для отправки ответа. Или нет?

Comment: Для отправки (в sendto) можно использовать любой UDP-сокет. См. [man 7 udp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html)

Comment: Я разобрался. По моему вопросу - да можно использовать слушающий серверный UDP сокет для отправки сообщения в sendto. В моём случаи была ошибка в том что я обращался к процедуре класса, а сокет, являющийся свойством класса, получается был не инициализирован. Нужно было просто обращаться к методу экземпляра класса. А касаемо отличающихся портов клиента в клиентской и серверной программе я отдельный вопрос задал